# Python matplotlib can't show binarized image

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I have python 3.8.7 installed on windows 10 x64 20h2. 
When I try to plot "normal" image it is working fine

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_img = io.imread('test.png')
plt.imshow(my_img)
plt.plot()
```

But when I apply binarization to image and then try to show it, it is not working

```
binarized_img = my_img > 100

plt.imshow(binarized_img, plt.cm.gray) #or cmp='gray'
plt.show()
```

It is giving me that error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
...
ValueError: Unsupported dtype
Exception in Tkinter callback
...
ValueError: Unsupported dtype
```

I pasted whole output to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.pl/view/3cd85d8b)

I don't know what to do. On that 20h2 compilation I have errors all the time (:

Comment: I think the kwarg is `cmap` not `cmp`

Comment: It could be, but it's not the main problem. I put it in comment anyway.

Comment: show `binarized_img.dtype`.

Comment: well, just a note. What dtype is your resulting image?

Comment: Before binarization it is showing: uint8
After: bool (???)

Comment: since the error has to do with dtype, I'd suggest casting your result to np.uint8 before trying to show it

Comment: I did sth like that `my_binary = np.array(my_img > 30, dtype=np.uint8)`
But it is not working still (no error, but it is showing white screen no matter what "threshold" I put)

Comment: If the PNG is a RGBA image (with alpha channel), the `alpha` channel is also set to either 1 or 0 which means nearly transparent.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late but in my case `my_binary = my_binary * 255` showed some information about threshold.